# React - Redirect user is not authenticated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I am using Firestore and have access to state that will inform me if the user is authenticated or not. I am mapping these conditions to props and will use `react-router-dom`'s redirect to navigate user to the login page if not authenticated.

However, when I console log the authentication status i see that initially it will show false while it loads this information and then switched to true. However, by the time it sees that the users is authenticated, I have already redirected them.

How am I suppose to redirect users based on their authentication within react?

```
export class PrimaryNavBar extends Component {
  
  render(){
    const { auth, location } = this.props;
    const authenticated = auth.isLoaded && !auth.isEmpty;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      {!authenticated ? <Redirect to="/"/> : null}
      <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Link to="/">
    ....
```

I have looked at other answers here but they don't really helped with redirects, just render nulls if not authenticated.

### Update

I restructured my code to redirects will happen in the app.js file

The new problem is, whenever I user changes route, it will recheck auth which will be false at first and they end up back at the login screen.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: this.props.isAuthenticated
  }

  render() {
    const logoutHandler = () => {
      this.props.firebase.logout();
    };
    const authenticated = this.props.auth.isLoaded && !this.props.auth.isEmpty;
    return (
      <Aux>
        {!authenticated ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path='/(.+)' render={() => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <PrimaryNavBar logout={logoutHandler} />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path="/auctions" component={Auctions} />
              <Route path="/auctions/:id" component={AuctionItem} />
              <Route path="/auctions/create-auction" component={CreateAuction} />
              <Route path="/bidders/create-bidder" component={CreateBidder} />
              <Route path="/bidders/:id" component={Bidder} />
              <Route path="/bidders" component={Bidders} />
            </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        )} />
        <ReduxToastr position="bottom-right" />
      </Aux>
    );
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.firebase.auth.uid,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  };
};

const mapDisptachToProps = dispatch => {
  return {};
};


export default withRouter(withFirebase(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDisptachToProps
  )(App)
));
```

Comment: If you are storing the auth state in a Redux store, why do you say the auth state will be false at first? If it has already been set previously? Based on what I can gather you have done I would put the auth check in a ComponentDidMount or useEffect block and run it's auth fetch of the data asynchronously. Then you know that you ahve a fixed state before moving on to any other checks.

Comment: Also I note you are using Redux, so how are you dispatching the action to get the auth data? Remember that React-Redux is synchronous and you will need to ahve some middleware for dealing with async calls to servers and api's. Something like Redux-thunk or Sagas

Comment: firebase does all this magic under the hood to see if the user is already logged in. During the lifecycle, authenticate will resolve to false as it takes time to load. I do a dispatch to log the users in from the login screen. I most of this working but now I an don't know how to direct users to the app if they are logged in. What happens now if every route sees they are authenticated and then redirects them back to dashboard(landing page)

Comment: I use Firebase myself. The point I am making is when you request the authentication token and then get the uid, this must be done asynchronously. Your code is not going to hang around and wait for the request to come in, but you can make it so. The request will return a promise, and then you can use .then() to grab the uid and update your local state. Only once that is complete do you want to carry on executing code and rendering subsequent components. Alternatively, if you want to update the Redux state you must use a middleware for async actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably wait untill `auth.isLoaded` is true? If thats the case, you could just do

```
const { auth, location } = this.props;
if (!auth.isLoaded) return null
```

This will refrain your nav component from rendering untill the authentication info is loaded. You might want to consider to implement this check (and the redirect) in a parent component level, though.

Comment: This did help making sure users were not redirected back to login screen during route changes but now I can't direct authenticated users to the application after they are logged in.

Comment: I just went into the login component and did a redirect if the user was logged in. Would feel cleaner if this was all done from app.js but it works, so moving on.